# Blender doesn't show "Jack" in user preferences system audio

Tags: customization, audio

I would like to use Blender with **Jack** (Jack Audio Connection Kit), but it's not available in user preferences > System tab...

[image]

I'm using Blender 2.77 on Linux Kubuntu 16.04 and **jack2** ([v1.9.11](https://github.com/jackaudio/jackaudio.github.com/wiki/Q_difference_jack1_jack2)), with Cadence and snd-aloop (alsa-to-jack trick). I also tried with pulseaudio jack-sink module, and also without any audio bridge, with no more luck.

I tried to launch Blender with "setaudio" option, while Jackd is running :

```
blender -setaudio JACK
```

No warning message, but still nothing in the audio device list.

I found on the web that Blender needs to be compiled with "Jack enabled in user-config.py". Thanks to @batFINGER I know now that official Blender release from blender.org actually **IS** compiled with jack support. (tested it by typing `bpy.app.build_options.jack` in python console, and it returned `True`.)

Any help on that subject will be much appreciated.

Comment: If jack is enabled should be in user pref sound menu.  To check type bpy.app.build_options.jack into the python console, will be True or False.  Have you considered  building blender yourself on linux, enable WITH_JACK and use the latest jack2.

Comment: Thanks @batFINGER. `build_options.jack` returns `True`, but no Jack button in user prefs menu. So it seems the problem comes from my system and not from Blender... I'm using jack2 (v1.9.11, see [here](https://github.com/jackaudio/jackaudio.github.com/wiki/Q_difference_jack1_jack2) about versions). I also use pulseaudio-jack-sink so maybe this confuses Blender to recognize Jack? Thanks for your help.